# Elasticsearch nest : Search query throwing error

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am implementing elastic search to get search records. But as I am applying search query its throwing below error:

Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'error', line 1, position 10.

I am using below code for elastic search:

```
Client.Search<Videos>(s => s.Query(q => q.Terms("video_id", arrVideoId))
                                   .From(0).Size(100)
                                   );
```

where **arrVideoId** is string array. Length of this array is minimum 4000

Please suggest some solution how I can run above statement and where I am doing wrong. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, an what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting? Can you show the exact `DebugInformation` message?

Comment: I am using Nest v1.0 And Elasticsearch.Net v1.0                                                                                               
**Debug Information :**
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Elasticsearch.Net.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in BuisnessLogic.dll

Comment: What version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: I am using elasticsearch v5.2, I have upgraded Elasticsearch.Net(v5.0) and Nest(v5.0) version, Now its not giving any error but it is not searching data and I am getting no result after searching. And I noticed that when I have **arrVideoId** record set under 500 then I am getting search result but if result set is above 2000 I don't get any data in searching. What this issue could be?

Comment: Is the response that's returned valid i.e. `.IsValid` is `true`? If not, what is the error message?

Comment: I am getting "invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on post" message.  Thanks